# Storing database credentials in Android apps

Tags: android, android-studio, security, decompiling

I am creating an app which needs to connect to database, for which I am using JDBC. For app to connect with database, credentials are passed to JDBC connection. How can I hide them, so that someone cant just decompile my app and access it? Ofcourse I cant ask user to enter those credentials. Hardcoding is out of question, I was thinking reading them from file, but I am not sure that that is safe either.

Comment: "I am creating an app which needs to connect to database, for which I am using JDBC" -- that is not a good plan. JDBC is not designed to be used across the public Internet, let alone over WiFi or mobile networks.

Comment: Which API do you think would be best for me to use then? Thank you.

Comment: Create a Web service that talks to your database, and have your app talk to the Web service.

Comment: Sorry I dont kniw much about that, will it solve my credentials problem too? Thank you.

Comment: ProGuard is one of the most used tools that shrinks, optimizes and obfuscates code. But it's a major question which determines if you're application is even worthy to hack and this relates to many questions i.e. who's hacking, how is he hacking, how much time will they spend, how much security can you afford and so on. In the end, in my opinion, no application in unbreakable but you can certainly strengthen the security on your side.

Comment: Honestly I just dont want it to be easy, if someone will have to spend some serious time hacking it,  its fine.